# Ffprobe - Достать продолжительность и битрейт

Tags: ffmpeg

```
ffprobe -i "+file+" -show_entries format=duration,bitrate -v quiet -of csv='p=0'
```

Достает только продолжительность, битрейта нет.
Собственно как достать продолжительность и битрейт. Желательно круглыми числами если возможно..

Comment: `bit_rate`. . .

Comment: `duration, bit_rate = map(int, sub.check_output("ffprobe -i "+file+" -show_entries format=duration,bit_rate -v quiet -of csv='p=0'", shell=True).decode().strip().split(','))  #в секундах
print(duration);` Работает, но из-за того что продолжительность с плавающей точкой. Выдает ошибку...